# How to get YQL to read my Open Data Table definition?

Tags: yql

Suppose I have an Open Data Table definition at a publicly accessible location such as `http://example.com/mytable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table xmlns="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/schema/table.xsd">
  ...
</table>
```

How can I run a query (e.g. `show tables`) against this definition?  Is there some way to import the table definition into the YQL console directly?

(The [example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-sample.html) doesn't explain how to get YQL to actually read the table definition--it leaves this bit as an exercise to the reader...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more tables can be manually imported by [using the `use` statement](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-import.html#yql-opentables-import-single):

```
use "http://example.com/mytable.xml" as mytable;
desc mytable;
```

If you have many tables, or want to reuse a bunch of them for different queries, then create a [YQL environment file](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-import.html#yql-opentables-import-environment), and use this in the console or the actual query URLs with the `env` GET parameter ([docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_url.html)).

See [Invoking an Open Data Table Definition within YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-import.html) for full details.